# Tabela MySQL com problema de performance (Muito lenta)

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela MYSQL com **apenas 31.000 registros** e ela está muito lenta quando vou fazer consulta, porém não tenho a mínima ideia de como resolver isso. O Script de criação dela é esse:

```
CREATE TABLE `PHOTOS_Data_Base` (
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_keywords` text NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_description` text NOT NULL,
    `FK_CONTRIBUTORS_User` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_current_file_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_original_file_upload_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_process_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_click_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_digitalization_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_resolution` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_width` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_height` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_extension` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_make` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_model` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_lens_model` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_orientation` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_components_number` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_metadata_JSON` text NOT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_title` tinytext,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_file_size` float(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `PHOTOS_Data_Base_original_file_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    `FK_PHOTOS_Data_Base_Origin` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `FK_PHOTOS_Data_Base_Status` int(3) NOT NULL,
    `FK_PHOTOS_Type` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`PHOTOS_Data_Base_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2107242773 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Um simples SELECT demora mais de 1 minuto para trazer as informações:

> SELECT * FROM PHOTOS_Data_Base WHERE FK_PHOTOS_Data_Base_Status = 2   15 row(s) returned  0.188 sec / 88.609 sec

Existe algum recurso do MYSQL para aumentar a velocidade dessa tabela?  Pois no futuro essa tabela receberá milhões de informações e ela mesmo com 30.000 registros já está lenta demais...

Comment: você criou a FK `FK_PHOTOS_Data_Base_Status` ? tenta criar um índice para essa coluna

Comment: @RovannLinhalis vou fazer o alter table e ver o resultado

Comment: Não sei sobre o problema ainda, mas não daria para usar nomes mais simples? `smallint(6)`? Tenho medo desse `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Existe um recurso, chama-se índice, conhece?

Comment: @Maniero Eu criei essa tabela a 1 ano e 3 meses atrás, eu era 100% cru em desenvolvimento ai eu tentei criar um padrão para os nomes, mas hoje eu acabo até me confundindo... Sobre o `smallint(6)` foi o phpMyAdmin que criou automaticamente. `AUTO_INCREMENT` está desse tamanho pois meu chefe pediu para iniciar de um número especifico. Conheço um pouco de indice, mas nunca apliquei, acredito que esse seja o momento.

Comment: o que é `PHOTOS_Data_Base_metadata_JSON` ?? é o binário do arquivo ??

Comment: @RovannLinhalis é um JSON com os metadados do arquivo de imagem. informações como cabeçalho IPTC, JFIF, EXIF, File System e etc.

Comment: @Maniero da uma olhada nessa pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/310488/77723

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti índice é tudo em DB, sem ele nem penso em DB.

Comment: Nao precisa necessariamente alterar a tabela com alter table para verificar a performance, crie um indice com o comando create index Data_Base_Status on PHOTOS_Data_Base(FK_PHOTOS_Data_Base_Status); e depois execute o select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie índices apontando para os campos mais usados como parâmetro de busca e se for o caso, ter certeza que as chaves estrangeiras estão devidamente referenciadas. A importância da existência de índices e de chave estrangeira é de que esses servem como um "farol" da tabela, que ajuda o serviço do banco de dados a encontrar os registros com mais exatidão e velocidade quando os parâmetros do where estão com esses índices referenciados.