# Qual a diferença entre SMALLINT(3) e INT(3)?

Tags: mysql, tipagem, armazenamento

Estou com uma duvida sobre a diferença entre dois tipos de dados no MySQL: [Esse documento](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) possui essa tabela:

| Type | Storage (Bytes) | Minimum Value Signed | Minimum Value Unsigned | Maximum Value Signed | Maximum Value Unsigned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TINYINT | 1 | -128 | 0 | 127 | 255 |
| SMALLINT | 2 | -32768 | 0 | 32767 | 65535 |
| MEDIUMINT | 3 | -8388608 | 0 | 8388607 | 16777215 |
| INT | 4 | -2147483648 | 0 | 2147483647 | 4294967295 |
| BIGINT | 8 | -2<sup>63</sup> | 0 | 2<sup>63</sup>-1 | 2<sup>64</sup>-1 |

A construção padrão desses tipos é `SMALLINT(M)` e `INT(M)` onde `M = numero máximo de dígitos que o campo irá receber`. Preciso armazenar a resolução de uma imagem que pode ser `72`, ou `240`, ou `300` DPI.

Qual a diferença entre esses dois campos se eu utilizar `SMALLINT(3)` ou `INT(3)`? Pois pelo que percebi a grande diferença está em **Storage** e **Min/Max Value Signed**

Comment: `72,240` é um número quebrado, sendo assim você não pode usar nenhum tipo de `int`.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos é uma virgula para separar os valores, na vdd são valores inteiros.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos corrigi

Comment: Isso me levantou uma bela questão. Vou perguntar!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bom, a tabela já mostra a diferença. Tentando usar outras palavras:

- o primeiro ocupa 2 bytes e permite 65536 números distintos, geralmente metade para cada lado
- o segundo ocupa ocupa 4 bytes e permite mais de 4 bilhões de variações sendo que o normal metade negativo e metade positivo. O que diferencia é a capacidade de armazenamento.

A questão do `3` nos parênteses é que será apresentado por padrão com 3 dígitos, o que não faz muito sentido para os dois casos, o 3 faz sentido para o `TINYINT`. Mas note que é só apresentação, não ocupa menos ou mais espaço, não muda precisão, exatidão, nada disso. É só quando apresenta no banco de dados.

Obviamente não vou repetir o que já está na pergunta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

A diferença é o intervalo de valores que aceitam (conforme a tabela), ou seja:

### Signed

SMALLINT: `-32768` a `32767`

INT: `-2147483648` a `2147483647`

### Unsigned

SMALLINT: `0` a `65535`

INT: `0` a `4294967295`

---

### Diferença do Signed para Unsigned

Cada tipo tem seu limite em bytes (ex.: SMALLINT 1 byte).

**Signed**: "divide" a quantidade possível entre negativos e positivos.

**Unsigned**: "não divide", assim, aceitando somente números positivos.

---

### Valor entre parêntese

Uma citação bem explicativa ([Fonte](https://rubsphp.blogspot.com/2013/06/declarando-tipos-numericos-no-mysql.html)):

> 5 - Os valores precisam ser preenchidos com zeros a esquerda ou tem
>   uma largura esperada?
>
> A resposta da quinta pergunta é usada apenas para formatação do
>   número. Se quisermos que os números sejam devolvidos com zeros a
>   esquerda, utilizamos o modificador "ZEROFILL". Já a "largura" dos
>   campos é usada para que a aplicação possa exibir o valor com espaços a
>   esquerda. A largura dos campos é devolvida entre as meta-informações
>   vindas de uma consulta.
>
> A largura é especificada de forma diferente para inteiros e reais. Nos
>   números inteiros, a largura é especificada entre parênteses, após o
>   nome do campo (por exemplo "INT(11)"). Para os números reais, a
>   largura é justamente a precisão do campo (citada anteriormente), a
>   diferença é que o número da precisão passa a ser a largura total do
>   campo, inclusive com a pontuação.
>
> A maior confusão que vejo por aí é a utilização da "largura" do campo
>   achando que ela é a "capacidade máxima de dígitos" do campo. Isso está
>   errado. Ou seja, se o campo é INT(1), INT(2) ou INT(11), seu valor
>   máximo continuará sendo "2.147.483.647". Para especificar campos com
>   maior ou menor capacidade, devem ser usadas as variações do campo
>   (TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT ou BIGINT para campos INT ou usar FLOAT
>   ou DOUBLE para campos de ponto flutuante).
>
> Observação: a opção ZEROFILL aplica automaticamente a opção UNSIGNED
>   no campo, mesmo que você tenha especificado SIGNED explicitamente.

---

**Concluindo sua pergunta:**

Poderá usar do `SMALLINT` ao `BIGINT` pois todos aceitam os valores: `72`, ou `240`, ou `300`.

O valor entre parêntese `(3)`, significa que sua coluna será limitada em 3 dígitos visíveis, mas os valores continuarão sendo possíveis conforme os limites do campo.

---

### Links úteis

[Documentação oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: Mas não tem nada de caracteres aí.

Comment: @Maniero verdade, eu comecei a pensar na minha pergunta e fui além.

Comment: Essencialmente o que está escrito aí é o que está na pergunta, o que tem de diferente é sobre o limitador de apresentação que não foi falado nada.

Comment: @Maniero complementada!

Answer (score -2):

## de acordo com a progressão, aceitar intervalos de números cada vez maiores.

```
tinyint = 1 byte
smallint = 2 bytes
mediumint = 3 bytes
int = 4 bytes
bigint = 8 bytes
```

Comment: Sim, isto está na tabela da pergunta.

Answer (score -2):

Quanto ao quantitativo de caracteres, totalmente de acordo. Quanto ao (3), há duas coisas a se pensar em utilizar isto.
Primeiro, você indicando o (3), seu BD vai sempre reservar este espaço específico para aquele valor, seja você incluindo valor com 1 ou 3 caracteres, o que vai melhorar no que se diz respeito à performance das queries, principalmente quando este BD começa a tomar proporções maiores.
Agora, se você pensar mais no espaço, sempre que indicar uma quantidade de caracteres específica,  este espaço será sempre reservado, ocupando mais espaço em memória do que um campo dinâmico, como 'int()'.
Obviamente, com um campo dinâmico, há a questão de que a query vai precisar primeiro verificar a quantidade de caracteres antes de retornar o valor, pois só poderá retornar após o mapeamento.

Resumindo (com exemplos para números inteiros INT):

Int(): Alocará a quantidade de memória dinamicamente, conforme a quantidade de caracteres incluídos.

Int(3): Alocará memória para 3 caracteres, indiferente se incluir 1 ou 999 em seu resultado.

Comment: Acho que sua resposta esbarra nisso: [Espaço ocupado entre diferentes tipos de inteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310513/espa%C3%A7o-ocupado-entre-diferentes-tipos-de-inteiros). Até o momento estou tentando saber se realmente inteiros reservam ou não os bytes. E se a resposta que deram for correta, a sua está incorreta.

Comment: Ele aloca espaço de acordo com o que você indicar... no caso do exemplo (3), vai alocar os 3 espaços, indiferente do tipo de inteiro que indicar... seja TINYINT ou um INT normal.

Comment: Acabaram de responder lá. Não é assim não. Você está falando exatamente a dúvida que eu tinha, pois o `VARCHAR` por exemplo, ele não aloca.

Comment: Bom, VARCHAR realmente é diferente de usar CHAR, por exemplo. VARCHAR(10) você limita em 10, mas não ocupa os 10 se escrever 'hello', por exemplo, ocupando apenas os 5 caracteres. Caso use CHAR(10), ele deve ocupar os 10 espaços.

Comment: Como disse na outra pergunta, isso me gerou muita dúvida, abri uma pergunta: [Reserva dinâmica de espaço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310528/reserva-de-espa%C3%A7o-com-varchar)

Comment: Bom, um negativo, mas você confundiu a minha resposta... Não é nada sobre VARCHAR nem se é INT ou BIGINT, mas sim quanto a (1), (2) ou (3), por exemplo.

Comment: Legal... Quando respondi não havia surgido seu retorno. Vamos esperar por uma nova informação para que tenhamos a resposta mais correta possível. Valeu.

Comment: Bruno, o negativo é por estar incorreta, já que os inteiros alocam os espaços. Se caso você tiver algum link que mostre o contrário, poste que vamos ver, e tirar o negativo caso esteja correta.

Comment: Você disse que está incorreta pois os inteiros alocam espaço, ou seja, é exatamente o que eu falei, mas tudo bem, irei procurar com calma assim que possível novamente.

Comment: Bruno, não foi o que disse, tanto que outros não entenderam dessa forma. O que está se entendendo na sua resposta é que os tipos inteiros não alocam espaço, a não ser que, defina um valor, como disse aqui: "Primeiro, você indicando o (3), seu BD vai sempre reservar este espaço específico para aquele valor, seja você incluindo valor com 1 ou 3 caracteres"

Comment: Reformule sua resposta, não há problema algum nisso. Eu também sou iniciante, aprendo observando ou errando, o importante é saber o correto!

Comment: Não, não falei que não aloca espaço. Eu falei que ele aloca memória conforme a quantidade de caracteres que indicar, no caso era INT(3).

Comment: Mas é exatamente o que está errado. Ele aloca toda memória. Independente do que você indicar. Está lá, na outra pergunta que fiz.

Comment: Acho que estamos falando a mesma coisa e discordando entre si. Revisado. Vê se é o que você também entendeu.

Comment: Não cara... "Int(): Alocará a quantidade de memória dinamicamente, conforme a quantidade de caracteres incluídos."  isso está errado! Os tipo inteiros alocam todo o espaço independente de ter o valor lá.

Comment: Em todo caso tirei o -1. Mas pelo que entendi até agora, está errado.

Comment: Bom, se é realmente isso, aprendi errado, desculpe então... Vou pesquisar assim que conseguir com calma aqui esta questão. Obrigado.

Comment: Se caso realmente for da forma que está dizendo, todos os demais estão errados. Com toda certeza iremos agradecer se tiver alguma documentação sobre isso para aprendermos o correto! É muito importante o feedback! Valeu!

Comment: Pode deixar, vou tentar trazer uma resolução, não para achar quem está certo, mas para que todos tenhamos uma informação correta. Vlw!