# Espaço ocupado entre diferentes tipos de inteiros

Tags: mysql, tipagem, alocação

Pela tabela da [documentação oficial MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html), e uma [pergunta aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310488/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-smallint3-e-int3), me surgiu uma dúvida.

Considerando a tabela:

| Type | Storage (Bytes) | Minimum Value Signed | Minimum Value Unsigned | Maximum Value Signed | Maximum Value Unsigned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TINYINT | 1 | -128 | 0 | 127 | 255 |
| SMALLINT | 2 | -32768 | 0 | 32767 | 65535 |
| MEDIUMINT | 3 | -8388608 | 0 | 8388607 | 16777215 |
| INT | 4 | -2147483648 | 0 | 2147483647 | 4294967295 |
| BIGINT | 8 | -263 | 0 | 263-1 | 264-1 |

Vamos supor que vou usar um `TINYINT` e um `BIGINT` para armazenar o mesmo valor (ex.: `240`).

---

**Pergunto:**

- Ele não "reserva" todos os bytes para aquele registro (seria dinâmico o espaço ocupado)?
- Se dinâmico, teriam os 2 o mesmo tamanho em espaço em disco?
- Se não "reserva" esse espaço, como ele "aumenta" depois?
- Isso muda de banco para banco?

Comment: `Ele não "separa" todos os bytes para aquele registro igual ao VARCHAR?` Não entendi o que isso quer dizer. E provavelmente o resto ficou sem sentido por isso.

Comment: Provavelmente o @RBZ quer saber se o bigint considera apenas os bytes mais significativos, descartando os bytes mais a esquerda que estejam zerados

Comment: @Maniero seria se ele "reserva" o espaço para quando for usar todo espaço necessário. Porque se ele faz isso, mesmo que o valor é igual para os 2 (240) o `BIGINT` ocupará mais espaço.

Comment: Alterei para ficar melhor.

Comment: "relacionadas": [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207849/tamanho-do-campo-ocupa-valor-total-definido), [link2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190799/por-que-%C3%A9-muito-utilizado-varchar255/190804#190804)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dados numéricos possuem espaço fixo sempre, quando você escolhe o tipo está determinando quanto de espaço ocupará na linha daquela tabela, não muda. E a tabela apresentada está mostrando isso. É igual em qualquer linguagem.

Então se você disse que quer um `BIGINT` ele ocupará 8 bytes, mas que pode armazenar algo que caiba em um tipo menor. É como em uma folha de papel, o espaço para colocar vários dígitos está lá, se você não usar todo espaço é problema seu. Se sempre não usar, provavelmente escolheu o tipo errado. Se tiver um número que não cabe no espaço também escolheu errado, dará erro tentar pôr lá.

`VARCHAR` é outra coisa, aí é um dado inerentemente variável. O que estamos falando aqui vai mais na linha do `CHAR` que tem o tamanho definido na sua declaração da estrutura da tabela. Só lembrando que o `CHAR` você define quantos caracteres terão naquela coluna, e aí não muda, se falar que é 10, será sempre 10, mesmo que não não use todos. E por isso talvez as pessoas acham que o [`SMALLINT(3)`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/310488/101) tem a ver com caracteres, e é outra coisa completamente diferente, os números tem o espaço alocado definido independente desse número nos parênteses.

Não é assim em todos os banco de dados, o SQLite por exemplo só tem o `INT`, e o tamanho ocupado varia de acordo com a precisão que o número exige. Ocupa de 1 byte (se não for nulo) até 9 bytes (cada byte extra adiciona uma multiplicação de 128 já que 1 bit é usado para informar se tem um novo byte apara avaliar, a não ser o nono byte que, se existir, pode multiplicar os 256 possíveis de um byte, o que faria ter 8 bytes úteis e um que é a soma do bits de controle.

Há reserva de todos os bytes, ainda não entendi porque pode dar a percepção contrária se a tabela apresentada deixa isso claro. E ainda não entendi se algumas das demais perguntas fazem sentido.

Mas nada impediria ser diferente, como é em alguns banco de dados. Em geral as linhas podem ter tamanhos diferentes por causa do `VARCHAR` ou algum tipo de `BLOB`, se o número também for assim, nada muda, em muitos casos, pode ser vantajoso. Pense em uma linha como se fosse sempre um `VARCHAR` que tem vários segmentos (um `BLOB` seria até melhor), e de fato internamente costuma ser tratado assim, há um chave, geralmente o `ID` e um valor (*key-value*) que seria esse `BLOB`. Já em um índice o par o que se chama chave é a chave que todo conhece e o valor é o `ID` ou outra PK da tabela.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É isso mesmo. as outras questões seriam entender se ele era variável, pois pensei que poderia ser como o `VARCHAR`. SE caso fosse, eu queria entender o armazenamento dele, e como ele iria "aumentar" já que não teria essa "reserva" de espaço.

Answer (score 1):

No caso dos ints, todo o espaço da variável int é alocado mesmo que o valor dela seja 1 ou 100. Existem até mesmo setores em grandes desenvolvedores que avaliam qual é a forma mais viável de declarar os tipos de campos em um banco de dados para maximizar a economia de espaço em disco.

Comment: Não entendi a segunda frase. Nem sei se isto responde o que foi perguntado, at´pe porque não sei se entendi a pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Realmente, eu acabei de responder no tópico que citou algo neste sentido.
Se fixar o tamanho, é memória que será utilizada, mesmo sem uso.
Gera uma facilidade para a pesquisa, melhorando performance (pois não precisa mapear os campos antes de retornar).
Quanto a ficar 'quebrado', fica como se fossem campos em branco para a memória, para preencher aquele espaço, diferente do dinâmico que vai alocando conforme a necessidade.

Comment: Não sei se entendi e se responde, mas pode ser que até a minha não, pode ser que a pergunta seja confusa.

Comment: Na verdade, o que aloca nos números seriam ao indicar a quantidade de caracteres, no caso usar um int(3), como no tópico citado ali... o tipo não, INT, TINYINT só limitam o intervalo dos números a serem incluídos e não a quantidade de caracteres, até onde sei.

Comment: Não, isto está errado.

Comment: Bom, então me desculpe, mas o que sei seria justamente essa alocação para que as queries tenham melhor performance pela redução do tempo com mapeamento do tamanho de cada valor (quantidade de caracteres).

Comment: Isso me gerou muita dúvida, abri uma pergunta: [Reserva dinâmica de espaço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310528/reserva-de-espa%C3%A7o-com-varchar)

Comment: @BrunoMartins não existe isso, não sei onde viu isto, mas está errado, a não ser que esteja falando de outra coisa e não estou entendendo. Porque isso sequer faz sentido.

Comment: Leia a resposta abaixo, onde diz: "Todo o espaço da variável é alocado mesmo que o valor seja 1 ou 100". Ela está com 2 positivos. É exatamente o que eu falei. Favor reavalie, creio que há uma confusão no que entendeu da resposta, só isso. Obrigado.