# Reserva dinâmica de espaço

Tags: sql

Em outras questões no SOpt, surgiu uma questão daquelas que geram dúvidas.

Sobre o tipo `VARCHAR`, que tem a alocação de espaço dinâmica conforme os dados armazenados, pergunto:

Tem diferença usar `VARCHAR` de `VARCHAR(2)`?

- **Se eu definir esse valor, ele irá reservar o espaço**?
- Isso afeta e/ou limita na visualização do campo?
- Afeta e/ou limita os dados do campo?
- Com tipos `INTEIROS` isso muda?

Comment: Qual é a diferença pra isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190799/101 Ali não tem tudo o que precisa? Nem junto com https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207849/101

Comment: É isso mesmo. O problema da pesquisa são esses títulos, ou eu ainda não aprendi pesquisar aqui cara. Eu sempre sofro. Isso responderia " Esse 255 é apenas uma informação de como ele deve ser mostrado em uma seleção, não quer dizer que ela vai ocupar esse espaço em disco. Não há desperdício."

Comment: Varchar(2) armazena dinamicamente até 2 caracteres. Como não informado qual o banco e nunca vi criar uma coluna com tipo varchar sem parametro, imagino que seja equivalente a 'text', ou seja armazena dinamicamente sem limite.

Comment: Mas eu peguei elas de um comentário seu há alguns minutos.

Comment: @LisângeloBerti isto tem erros ou imprecisões, até pela ambiguidade da pergunta.